# htaccess condition user-agent

Tags: .htaccess, user-agent

What I'm trying to do is define a rule in my htaccess file that only applies to Internet Explorer:

```
Header set Connection close
```

I want this to only apply to Internet Explorer Users (ideally only IE11), I googled this but found no solution and I'm not that experienced when it comes to htaccess. How can I do this? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do something like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 11" [NC]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Connection "close"
</IfModule>
```

Make sure [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) is enabled though

Comment: are you sure this works? If I try that in firefox, the header still says "connection: close"

Comment: I tested that with Opera (using Opera instead of MSIE) and it worked fine. Unfortunately i don't have IE 11 to check that, but worked fine with Opera like I said